# 'button.setImage' is not working when ViewController (containing it) is in background

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the delegation pattern for my CoreBluetooth based app. I have a main ViewController that is a delegate to my BLEHandler class. I'm updating a button based on the response I get from following delegate method:

```
    func acIsOn(error: NSError?) {
      if error == nil{
          pushButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "state4"), for: .normal)
      }
    }
```

It works fine when my delegate controller class is in the foreground but when I move to another ViewController and calls a method of handler class that in response calls the delegate method above, the button on the image is not updated.

Here's what I have already tried:

1. Wrapping the statement in `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`
2. Calling `pushButton.setNeedsLayout()` and `setNeedsDisplay()`

But none of it worked. ,

Also I made sure that this method was being called when the ViewController is not in the foreground.

**Edit 1:** I'm more interested in learning about the limitation that is not allowing this to happen, I'm not looking for hacks/tricks to bypass this.

**Edit 2:** As mentioned by Shoazab, button.setBackgroundImage() is working when the VC is in background. Still curious why button.setImage doesn't work in background but it does in when VC is on top.

Comment: Are you sure that the state of the button is .normal?

Comment: @FedeHenze yes.

Comment: "Also I made sure that this method was being called when the ViewController is not in the foreground." means that the viewController is not visible when the function is called? is the entire app in Foreground or Background?

Comment: @FedeHenze yes it means that ViewController (controlling that button) is not visible but app is running in foreground showing another VC.

Comment: Now make sense, try to add a flag in the viewController to know when the UI should be updated and call the UI changes in the viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to changed an UI element on a ViewController which is not currently displayed. It will update values but no refresh on UI will be executed.

I think that calling  `SetNeedsDisplay` on method `viewWillAppear` on your ViewController will fix your problem.
You can also use a variable Image and update the button Image when the controller is displayed again.

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` in `viewWillAppear` didn't work. Yes I could do it using a variable image but I'm trying to learn the problem here. thanks!

Comment: Do you use a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, I'm using navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

Move the UI update code to the viewWillAppear like this:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, BLEHandler {

 var isUIUpdateNeeded = false

 //Define your UI outlets or proeprties

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }


 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     if isUIUpdateNeeded {
         updateUI()
     }
 }

 func acIsOn(error: NSError?) {
     if error == nil{
         pushButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "state4"), for: .normal)
     }
 }

 func updateUI() {
     //do your UI changes here
     pushButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "state4"), for: .normal)
 }

}
```

Comment: thanks! Olivier said similar thing but I just want to know why the current code is not updating it, what is the limitation?

Answer (score 1):

Call btn.setBackgroundImage()  it will set it